# Is there a way to move instance or snapshot across different projects

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am looking to move GCE instance or snapshot to different project I have access to. Is that something available in GCE?

Comment: I think you should take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29585381/google-compute-engine-use-snapshot-from-another-project - I guess it can be adapted to your use case

Answer (score 4):

There aren't any features by default that would allow you to move them to a different project. However, there are workarounds. The following is probably just one of many ways to do so.

To save a disk across projects you will need to use an image.  If you can’t use the standard [imagebundle](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-packages) tool, you can use the ["dd" command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_(Unix)). On a temporary disk that’s bigger than the one you want to image, run this:

```
$ dd if=/dev/disk/by-id/google-diskname of=disk.img bs=5M
```

You can then run the following to copy it over to Google Cloud Storage for example:

```
$ gsutil cp disk.img gs://yourbucket/your-image.img
```

And later, you can:

```
$ gsutil cat gs://yourbucket/your-image.img | \
     dd of=/dev/disk/by-id/google-newdisk bs=5M
```

In summary, you can make an image of your disk, use GCS to send it to over to another project and then use the 'snapshot' on the newly created disk to have a ready image based on which you can create additional instances for that project.

PS: It is also possible to create custom images for use in GCE. If you create a properly configured custom image, you can have it uploaded to any project and create instances directly from it. [See this article.](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images#buildingimage)

Comment: I am not able to copy it on google bucket. it is showing "ResumableUploadAbortException: 403 Insufficient Permission"