# How to move instance with attached Standard persistent disk to another project in GCE ?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have an instance with 1TB disk attached in a project. I want to move it on another project? i read this 
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images?hl=en#import_an_image 
but didn't get that.

Comment: You can use one of the steps on this answer to clone your disk in other project:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29585381/google-compute-engine-use-snapshot-from-another-project