# Best way to transfer data between vm instaces in different projects in Google cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

in my project vm1 has 1 TB and vm2 has 1.5TB data . i want to backup and copy those data to another vm in a different project(that project in different organization).

what is the best way to do this first I've tried compress data in vm1 and upload to cloud storage bucket but it's more time consuming.

Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at this question: [Compute Engine use Snapshot from another Project]( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29585381/google-compute-engine-use-snapshot-from-another-project) - faster than gsutil since you work directly with the underlying datacenter storage from Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do it.

**If this is a Linux machine you can use `rsync`** to synchronise several folders on remote machines - it can be ran using `cron` daily or hourly - depending on how often you want to backup to be created. Here's a very informative

You can try to compress the data before the transfer but it will take a lot of time (considering that you have over 1TB).

**In my opinion fastest way would be to transfer uncompressed data over the Internet**
[you will be charged for egress traffic](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/network-pricing) (from 0,01USD/GB even up to 0,15USD/GB !).

You can't use [Shared VPC](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/shared-vpc) because this is only possible inside an organisation and you have VM's in different orgs;

> Shared VPC connects projects within the same organization

**You can use other protocols to do the transfer such as FTP, use Samba or just regular folder sharing in Windows** (if we're talking about such machines) or some `rsyn` relative for Windows such as [cwRsync](https://itefix.net/cwrsync).

If you provide more details about your use case then I can update my answer and provide more up-to-the-point solution.

Comment: hey thank you for answer i'm going to use NFS server to get backups from vm and after getting backups share NFS server disk to other project.